# Eclipseでtomcatプロジェクトを作成している時、conf/Catalina/localhost/[app].xml ファイルを指定する方法

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Eclipseでtomcatのプロジェクトを作成しているのですが conf/Catalina/localhost/[app].xml ファイルを指定するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか
[image: Eclipseの説明画像]
添付画像の通り、tomcatTest20150719プロジェクトから設定ファイルを外出ししようと、tomcatText20150719.xml をtomcatプロジェクトの中に配置したのですが
実行してもtomcatText20150719.xmlが反映されません。

(実際は catalinaBaseがEclipseデフォルトの設定でworkspace\base.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0 の中に作成されるのですが、この中にtomcatTest20150719.xmlがコピーされない)
catalinaBaseに、tomcatTest20150719.xmlを反映させるにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse WTPをお使いのようですね。
WTPではサーバの設定をまずTomcatからコピーしています。そこでサーバごとの環境依存となる設定をServers＞Tomcat v8.0Serverの中へ直接記載します。Eclipse上で修正したものは、インストールされているTomcatの設定ファイルは直接上書きせず、あくまでWTPで動作するときの設定としてEclipseが扱えるようになっております。

また、catalinaBaseに配置されるのはWebアプリケーション(warファイルの中身)だけです。
サーバの設定は展開されません。

なお、外出ししたxmlファイルはTomcatの設定を記載したものなのでしょうか、それともWebアプリケーションで参照するものなのでしょうか。Webアプリケーション内部で使うものでしたら、Webアプリケーションの中に同梱しなければなりませんし、サーバの設定であれば、Serversの中に表示されているディレクトリへ直接配置します。

Comment: まず、Servers＞Tomcat v8.0Server～ は、サーバー設定と定義し以下のパス
workspace\Servers\Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config
catalinaBaseは以下のパス
workspace\base.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
にあります。

>catalinaBaseに配置されるのはWebアプリケーション(warファイルの中身)だけです。サーバの設定は展開されません。

との事ですが、ファイルを見るとcatalinaBaseのconfディレクトリの中にサーバー設定のファイルがコピーされています。
実際にサーバー設定の中にhoge.txt を作ると、catalinaBase/confの中にhoge.txt がコピーされました。
なのに、サーバー設定の中のCatalina/localhost/[app].xml を作ってもcatalinaBase/confの中に反映されないのかと思ったのですが、どうもコピー処理はディレクトリはコピーされないみたいです。

warファイルの”外”にアプリの設定を配置したい(warファイルを共通化したい)と思ったのですが、ご指摘の通りよろしくなさそうなのでアプローチを変えてみます。
ありがとうございました。